# How to make box shadow stay when you add another div below it?

Tags: html, z-index, css

The navbar on my website has a box shadow below it, but for some reason when I add another div below it (which is essentially just a giant image), the box shadow on the navbar dissapears and it's almost as if the image overlaps the navbar, or at least the box shadowing of it. Below are 2 images showing what I mean.

Without div/image below - http://puu.sh/3Iw9F.png
With div/image below - http://puu.sh/3Iwbx.jpg

I tried messing around with some z-index, but got no luck. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
    <div id="navbar">
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
     </div>

    <div id="images">
        <img src="image/image1.jgp" />
    </div>
```

---

```
    #navbar {width:100%;padding:10px 0px;text-align:center;z-index:100;box-shadow: inset 0 1px #fff, 0 1px 3px rgba(34,25,25,0.4);-moz-box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(34,25,25,0.4);-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(34,25,25,0.4);}
    #navbar a {text-decoration:none;padding:5px 10px;border:1px solid #fff;font-size:16px;font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;color:#3f3f3f;font-weight:900;border-radius:3px;-moz-border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;}
    #navbar a:hover {background:#F26311;border:1px solid #E0570F;color:#fff;text-shadow:0px 2px 2px #E0570F;}

    #images {width:100%;}
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Try put `position: relative` to your `div#navbar`. The reason the box-shadow disappear is your `div#images` overlap it

Answer (score 0):

You could try to contain them both in another div.

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="navbar">
  </div>
  <div id="images">
  </div>
</div<
```

Then put the shadow on the wrap It should show on the bottom of the images.
Or anything you would add to the `wrap` div.

Also another option instead of containing them in a div. You could add padding on the navigation and then `position:relative; top:x;` the image div.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that when you add a shadow that shadow is not included in the div. What you need to do it put padding on the bottom of your menu bar so that there is room for your shadow.